# Why can't I use `allAuthenticatedUsers` for my Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

When deploying Firebase Functions using the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli), they are configured so that the *Cloud Functions Invoker* permission is granted to `allUsers`. With such a setting the code below functions as expected.

The *Cloud Functions Invoker* permission can also be granted to `allAuthenticatedUsers`. However, when I implement this change for `addMessage`, I only ever get a `UNAUTHENTICATED` error response using the code below.

Why won't `allAuthenticatedUsers` work for this Firebase Cloud Function?

---

**Note:** This Q&A is a result of a now-deleted question posted by [Furkan Yurdakul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6276596/), regarding why `allAuthenticatedUsers` wasn't working with his Firebase Callable Function for his Firebase app

---

MWE based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), with `addMessage` defined [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/df727af9a7a4d29b1e067c1573ebb9a9dd760f04/functions/functions/index.js#L56-L103):

```js
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously() // for the sake of the MWE, this will normally be Facebook, Google, etc
  .then((credential) => {
    // logged in successfully, call my function
    const addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');
    return addMessage({ text: messageText });
  })
  .then((result) => {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function.
    const sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
    alert('The sanitized message is: ' + sanitizedMessage);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // something went wrong, keeping it simple for the MWE
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;

    if (errorCode === 'auth/operation-not-allowed') {
      alert('You must enable Anonymous auth in the Firebase Console.');
    } else {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put, if the ID token passed to a Cloud Function represents a Google account (that used Google Sign-In through [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) or [Google itself](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#google_sign-in)), it works, otherwise, it doesn't.

Think of `allAuthenticatedUsers` as `allAuthenticatedGoogleUsers` instead of `allAuthenticatedFirebaseUsers`.

#### Background Information

For [Callable Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) used with the Firebase Client SDKs, you will normally grant `allUsers` the permission to call it (the default setting [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) deployed functions).

A [valid authenticated client request](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) for a Google Cloud Functions must have an `Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN` header (preferred) or `?access_token=ID_TOKEN`. Here, `ID_TOKEN` is a signed-in Google user's ID token as a [JWT](https://jwt.io).

When Firebase Client SDKs call a Callable Function, they set the `Authorization` header for you with the current user's [ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) (if the user is signed in, [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/7b585e8e7bc6bdc36200681865ec11e91ca7c4a1/packages/functions/src/api/service.ts#L249-L251)). This is done so that the user's authentication token can be used in the [`context` parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext) of [`onCall()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#oncall) functions. Importantly though, a Firebase user's ID token doesn't always represent a Google user which makes it incompatible with `allAuthenticatedUsers`.

Because of this, you will have to gate your callable function in your code by checking [`context.auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext#optional-auth) and it's properties like below.

```js
export const addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    // Throwing a HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'failed-precondition',
      'The function must be called while authenticated.'
    );
  }

  // a valid user is logged in

  // do work
});
```

---

#### Addendum on 403 Forbidden Errors

If your function is consistently throwing a 403 error after being deployed, this is likely because you are using an outdated copy of the Firebase CLI, as highlighted in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function):

> Caution: New HTTP and HTTP callable functions deployed with any Firebase CLI lower than version 7.7.0 are private by default and throw HTTP 403 errors when invoked. Either explicitly [make these functions public](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access) or [update your Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#setup_update_cli) before you deploy any new functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me! BTW, you might want to use `'unauthenticated'` as the HttpsError code as it's more indicative of the issue.