# Firebase functions run in one firebase project but giving internal error in the other

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have two firebase accounts one used for development(D) and the other for production(P). My development(D) firestore and functions run on us-central1. On production(P) firestore location is asia-south1 and functions run on us-central1

My firebase functions run properly in development (D) but are giving me the following error in production. Further, when I check the logs on the firebase functions console, there does not seem to be any activity. It appears as if the function has not been called.

Error returned by firebase function is :

> Function call error Fri Apr 09 2021 09:25:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)with{"code":"internal"}

Further the client is also displaying this message :

> Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/gpublish' from origin 'https://setmytest.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. zone-evergreen.js:1052 POST https://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/gpublish net::ERR_FAILED

Here is the code from my angular app calling the function -

```
const process = this.fns.httpsCallable("gpublish");
process(data).subscribe(
  (result) => {
    console.log("function responded with result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
  },
  (err) => {
    const date1 = new Date();
    console.log("Function call error " + date1.toString() + "with" + JSON.stringify(err));
  });
```

Here are the functions -

index.ts

```
import { gpublish } from "./gpublish/gpublish";
import { sendEmail } from "./sendEmail";

export {gpublish,sendEmail };
```

gpublish.ts

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const fs = require("fs");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const script = google.script("v1");
const scriptId = "SCRIPT_ID";
const googleAuth = require("google-auth-library");
import { admin } from "../admin";
const db = admin.firestore();

export const gpublish = functions.https.onCall(async (data: any, res: any) => {
  try {
    const googleTest = data.test;
    console.log("Publishing to google test of name " + googleTest.testName);
    
    // read the credentials and construct the oauth client
    const content = await fs.readFileSync("gapi_credentials.json");
    const credentials = JSON.parse(content); // load the credentials
    const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.web;
    const functionsOauth2Client = new googleAuth.OAuth2Client(client_id,client_secret, redirect_uris); // Constuct an auth client
    functionsOauth2Client.setCredentials({refresh_token: credentials.refresh_token}); // Authorize a client with credentials

    // run the script
    return runScript(functionsOauth2Client,scriptId,JSON.stringify(googleTest)
    ).then((scriptData: any) => {
      console.log("Script data is" + JSON.stringify(scriptData));
      sendEmail(googleTest, scriptData);
      return JSON.stringify(scriptData);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return JSON.stringify(err);
  }
});

function runScript(auth: any, scriptid: string, test: any) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    script.scripts
      .run({auth: auth,scriptId: scriptid, resource: {function: "doGet", devMode: true,parameters: test }
      })
      .then((respons: any) => { resolve(respons.data);})
      .catch((error: any) => {reject(error);});
  });
}
```

I have changed the service account key and google credentials correctly when deploying the functions in development and in production.

I have tried many things including the following:

- [Enabling CORS in Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
- [Google Cloud Functions enable CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693758/google-cloud-functions-enable-cors)

The function is running perfectly in Development firebase project but not in Production firebase project. Please help!

Comment: I discovered that when setting unauthenticated access for the function it runs perfectly. How do I ensure the httpsoncall function can run with authentication? Pls help

Comment: Firebase Functions must be left "public". The `allAuthenticatedUsers` option only works for signed-in Google accounts (because they are actually Google Cloud Functions) and not with Firebase Authentication accounts. You need to use `context.auth` to deny access to your function. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66814095/3068190)

Comment: Thanks, I was worried about giving access to AllUsers but I have implemented this now. It works!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that your function has been deployed correctly.

A function that doesn't exist (`404 Not Found`) or a function that can't be accessed (`403 Forbidden`) will both give that error as the Firebase Function is never executed, which means the correct CORS headers are never sent back to the client.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful to understand the error message of "internal" returned by firebase.