# Firebase functions authorize only requests from Firebase hosting app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

I have a simple Firebase Hosting web application (based on a Vue app) which invokes Firebase Function (Google cloud function):

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/functions";


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let functions = firebase.app().functions("us-west4");
let testFunction = functions.httpsCallable("testFunction");
```

and corresponding functions `index.js` file:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.testFunction = functions.region("us-west4").https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log("Very important things here");
  return {"response": "data"};
});
```

From security perspective is it possible to

1. Allow this invocation only from my domain name (Firebase hosting) `myhostedapp.web.app`
2. Check for any kind of authentication (e.g. token) that my JS app provides during the request?

I've tried accessing `context.auth` property ([see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function)) buth seems like some kind of service account is required and this cannot be used when called from Firebase hosting web application.

Basically I don't want my function to be publicly accessible (simple invocation via trigger url), so any advice or best practice for securing `Firebase Hosting + Functions` would be appreciated.

[image: unauth]

Comment: Regarding the "Allow unauthenticated" part for the cloud functions, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66814095/3068190) for information on why it's needed to be that way. Note: I haven't updated it with info on the new [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase just released a new feature called [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) that does precisely this: it allows the Cloud Functions in your project to only be invoked from apps that are registered in that project.

For [web apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web) this happens through reCAPTCHA v3, which . Then once you [enable enforcement](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions) of the check on Cloud Functions, it will reject any requests coming from other sources.

You'll typically want to combine App Check with your current user-based approach, so that you can easily block calls from outside your web app, but also still ensure authenticated users only can make calls that they're authorized for.